# Exit command with any key

Tags: automation

Here's what I have:

A script that records sound and exits when pushing ctrl+c

```
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd -t wav -d 0 -q -r 16000 > file
```

This will record and record until I push ctrl+c

I want to simulate the ctrl+c action, by pushing any key (preferably one keystroke)

Comment: Is it important to you to actually simulate a Ctrl+C keypress, or would other methods of stopping the recording be acceptable as long as they were triggered by pressing any key?

Comment: Any method of stopping the recording would be perfectly fine. There is more to the script, so I need it to be able to continue along without going on forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stty in a subshell and change the setting for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to whatever. In my example I changed it to <kbd>x</kbd>. After the subshell is ended or interrupted by <kbd>x</kbd> the setting will be restored to ^c (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>).

```
user@host:~# (stty intr x && arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd -t wav -d 0 -q -r 16000 > file); stty intr ^c
```

Even if you kill the process via `killall acroread` the setting will be restored.

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed by this one. It's not any key, but it's one line and doesn't require a enter after pushing the intr keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use bash as your shell(you can change the shell if its other than bash, in the first line of the script):

```
#!/bin/bash
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd -t wav -d 0 -q -r 16000 > file &
pid_of_arecord=`pidof arecord`
read input
kill -2 $pid_of_arecord
```

This sends the [SIGINT signal](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal%207) to `arecord` wheneven you press *any key* after starting the recording.